# Flutter - TextField "textAlign" property not found

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter

I have this basic textfield:

```
          new TextField(
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blue),
            onChanged: (InputValue newInputValue) {
              setState(() {
                inputValue = newInputValue;
            });
          }),
```

I now want to make the text float to the center when the user types something in. So I went to the docs and it told me to use the textAlign property.

```
              new TextField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center;
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.blue),
                onChanged: (InputValue newInputValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    inputValue = newInputValue;
                });
              }),
```

But for some reason, Flutter tells me that the property TextAlign does not exist.

Comment: What commit are you on? It seems `textAlign` was only added a month ago: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/0b31c699637e84377f991b357e2ab9c0ef0af3f0

Comment: Yep, upgrading solved the issue.. could have thought about that, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to upgrade flutter and it worked. TextAlign has been added very recently...